# QPropertyAnimation for the "visible" Property of QWidgets only works one way

Tags: qt, animation, qt5.6

I have a task were I need to execute a sequence of PropertyAnimations. One of the animations is changing the visibility of a QWidget. When I try to hide it, it works perfectly fine:

```
QPropertyAnimation *pAnim = new QPropertyAnimation(pWidget, "visible");
pAnim->setStartValue(true);
pAnim->setEndValue(false);
pAnim->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

But when I try it the other way around, nothing happens:

```
QPropertyAnimation *pAnim = new QPropertyAnimation(pWidget, "visible");
pAnim->setStartValue(false);
pAnim->setEndValue(true);
pAnim->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or might this be a bug in Qt? 
I am using Qt 5.6.1 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I got from the Qt support:

> bool is not interpolatable type which results in invalid QVariant, which just
>   happens to convert to false, so boolean properties can never be set to true by
>   default.[..]
>
> It is probably better to make your own QAbstractAnimation subclass which just
>   sets the property to new value. However, you can of course define your
>   interpolation function for bool for it. For example:
>
> static QVariant bool_interpolator(const bool& from, const bool& to, qreal
>   progress) { return progress < 0.5 ? from : to; }
>   ...
>   qRegisterAnimationInterpolator(bool_interpolator);

I tested the solution with interpolator and it worked exactly as I needed it.